# Can an 18 year old with just a permit drive alone in Colorado?

Tags: driving, colorado

If you are under 18 [with a permit], Colorado driving laws prohibit you to drive alone. You must be accompanied by a parent, legal guardian, a driver’s education instructor, or a licensed driver at least 21 years old whenever you go out for a drive.
What if you are over 18? I haven't found any sources that seem to indicate one way or another whether an 18 year old with permit but not licence can drive alone.

Comment: If this were allowed, presumably nobody over 18 would bother gettting a full licence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Colorado Drivers Handbook](https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/sites/default/files/DR2337.pdf) says:

> Instruction permits: An instruction permit allows
>   limited driving privileges for people learning to drive.
>   **Regardless of age, if you are driving with an instruction
>   permit, you must be accompanied by a person 21 years
>   of age or older who holds a valid Colorado license** and is
>   riding in the seat beside you.

(Emphasis mine)

So if you are an adult, regardless of your age, you are required to have somebody 21 years of age or older who has a valid Colorado drivers license. An 18 year old (or anybody for that matter) with just an instruction permit may not drive alone.

In Colorado adults (21 years of age or older) are required to get a permit, but there is no time requirement to hold it before taking the written and driving test to obtain a regular (Class-R) drivers license.

Comment: This being [Law.SE], the answer would probably be better off citing the actual law that controls this rather than the manual, or in addition to it.